# Recode algorithm for merged cells on HTML table

Tags: php, algorithm, array

Is there any way to improve this algorithm maybe making it so faster avoid using foreach? Maybe with a recursion?
The output of my algorithm is a table with 3 merged columns, each row will have its own rowspan.

```
$matrix=array("person1"=>array("wifes"=>array("diana"=>array("born"=>1982,"last_name"=>"chapelle"),"carla"=>array("born"=>1983,"last_name"=>"michael"),"serena"=>array("born"=>1984,"last_name"=>"mickelson")
            ,"king"=>array("born"=>1980,"last_name"=>"jordan")))
    ,"person2"=>array("husbands"=>array("charles"=>array("born"=>1983,"last_name"=>"rambo")
    ,"minglen"=>array("born"=>1973,"last_name"=>"rian"),"serrano"=>array("born"=>1914,"last_name"=>"kingside"))));

$htmlx="<table border='1'>";
    $htmlx.="<tr>";
    $htmlx.="<th>object</th><th>type</th><th>names</th><th>detail_names</th><th>values_detail</th>";
    $html_p=NULL; $p=0; 
    foreach ($matrix as $pkey => $pvalue) {
        $t=0;   $html_t=NULL;
        foreach ($pvalue as $tkey => $tvalue) {
            $n=0;   $html_n=NULL;   $rs_general=0;
            foreach ($tvalue as $nkey => $nvalue) {
                $d=0;   $html_d=NULL;   $rs_general+=count($nvalue);
                foreach ($nvalue as $dkey => $dvalue) {

                    $d++;
                    if($d==1){
                        $html_d="<td>".$dkey."</td><td>".$dvalue."</td>";
                    }else{
                        $html_d.="<tr><td>".$dkey."</td><td>".$dvalue."</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
                $n++;
                if($n==1){
                    $html_n.="<td rowspan='".count($nvalue)."'>".$nkey."</td>".$html_d;
                }else{
                    $html_n.="<tr><td rowspan='".count($nvalue)."'>".$nkey."</td>".$html_d."</tr>";
                }
            }
            $t++;
            if($t==1){
                $html_t="<td  rowspan='".$rs_general."'>".$tkey."</td>".$html_n;
            }else{
                $html_t.="<tr><td  rowspan='".$rs_general."'>".$tkey."</td>".$html_n."</tr>";
            }
        }
        $p++;
        if($p==1){
            $html_p.="<td rowspan='".$rs_general."'>".$pkey."</td>".$html_t;
        }else{
            $html_p.="<tr><td rowspan='".$rs_general."'>".$pkey."</td>".$html_t."</tr>";
        }

    }
    $htmlx.="</tr>".$html_p;
$htmlx.="</table>";
echo $htmlx;
```

I have been thinking about recursion function but I don’t get the solution yet, so any help will be welcome.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? I see 4 `foreach` in each other, I'm wondering what made you think that was the obvious solution.

Comment: Hi Mast, What i see on my algorithm is that i have one foreach for every level or deep of my array, what i want is, find a way to improve it or make it more readable, faster. I have seen some people who uses recursion function but didn't get the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips to make it faster

1. Use references in foreach loops with **&**, like `foreach ($matrix as $pkey => &$pvalue)`
2. Don't use `$htmlx` variable, just output everything with `echo`
3. For some scecific purposes you may use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()` - it's much faster than concat like `$html_d.=`
4. Don't output html with php, just close php tags

   ```
   if($d==1){ ?>
      <td><?php echo $dkey ?></td><td><?php echo $dvalue ?></td>
   <?php }else{ ?>
   ```

Comment: It's interesting your recommendations but can you bring me a sample about ob_start(), ob_get_contents()...., and i need a variable $html because i need to draw while I'm drawing my tr's for computing rowspans, so ono.